# React refreshes component after function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a portfolio where to display all of my ML projects that can be displayed with a simple API call and I decided to create a WebApp. I'm using React for the frontend and Django for the backend. The goal is to make a single page that doesn't need to refresh or change the page.

I've pretty much done everything, but on testing the API for the first project, I notice that after the API's function call, the page refreshes and I can't seem to figure out why it does.

App Component:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menu: 1,
      file: null
    };
  }

  fileSelect = event =>{
    this.state.file = event.target.files[0];
  }

  update_menu_item(new_item){
    this.setState({menu: new_item});
  }

// HERE PROBLEM
  uploadSelfie(){
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.state.file)
    axios
    .put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/obtainFaceEmotionPrediction", fd)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data){
        // window.alert(response.data.file);
        // Here even if I were to delete everything in this if statement, it would still refresh the page
        document.getElementById("article").innerHTML +=
              "<img src='../frontend/public/pictures_saved/face_emotion/" + response.data.file + "'/>";
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  uploadMilitary(){
    // code not finalized yet. will be similar with uploadSelfie function but will handle multiple pictures
  }


  generate_segment(){
    let uiItems = [];

    if(this.state.menu === 1){
      uiItems.push(
        <article id="article">
          <h2 id="title">My ML Projects</h2>
          <div id="options">
            <ul>
              <li><button className="active" id="about" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(1)}>About</button></li>
              <li><button id="face_emotion_detection" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(2)}>Face Emotion Detection</button></li>
              <li><button id="military_detection" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(3)}>Military Detection</button></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <p>The scope of this application is to showcase all of the ML projects that I have finished. The application features a WebApp where the frontend is designed in React and the backend in Django.</p>
          <p>Using REST API I'm able to make a call from the frontend to the backend. There, depending on the selected project, a pre-trained ML model will take your input and serve your request.</p>
          <p>If you want to check the source code for each of these projects and more, you can do so by using this <a href="https://github.com/LCCosmin?tab=repositories">link</a>.</p>
        </article>
      )
    }
    else if(this.state.menu === 2){
      uiItems.push(
          <article id="article">
            <h2 id="title">My ML Projects</h2>
            <div id="options">
              <ul>
                <li><button id="about" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(1)}>About</button></li>
                <li><button className="active" id="face_emotion_detection" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(2)}>Face Emotion Detection</button></li>
                <li><button id="military_detection" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(3)}>Military Detection</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <p>The aim of this project is to detect both the face and the emotion of a person. Upload a selfie with you and see how the model works:</p>
            <input
              type="file"
              name="picture"
              id="picture"
              placeholder="Upload a Selfie"
              onChange={this.fileSelect}
            />
              <input
                type="button"
                value="Submit"
                onClick={(e) => this.uploadSelfie()}
              />
          </article>
        )
    }
    else{
      uiItems.push(
          <article id="article">
            <h2 id="title">My ML Projects</h2>
            <div id="options">
              <ul>
                <li><button id="about" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(1)}>About</button></li>
                <li><button id="face_emotion_detection" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(2)}>Face Emotion Detection</button></li>
                <li><button className="active"  id="military_detection" onClick={(e) => this.update_menu_item(3)}>Military Detection</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <p>The aim of this project is to detect military personnel from an input data. The input can be a picture or a video, however for this WebApp, currently it is supported only images input. If you would like to test the video feature, check out the git repository. Upload a picture with military personnel and see how the model works:</p>
            <input
              type="file"
              name="picture"
              id="picture"
              placeholder="Upload a Picture with Military"
              onChange={this.fileSelect}
            />
            <input
              type="button"
              value="submit"
              onClick={(e) => this.uploadMilitary()}
            />
          </article>
        )
    }

    return uiItems;
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <main>
        

        {this.generate_segment()}
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The API returns a simple strings and save a picture on the SSD:

API view:

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def obtainFaceEmotionPrediction(request):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        if request.FILES.get("image", None) is not None:
            img = request.FILES["image"]
            img = img.read()
            model = FaceEmotionRecognition()
            img = model.detect_emotion(img)

            dir = '../frontend/public/pictures_saved/face_emotion/'
            for f in os.listdir(dir):
                os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))

            cv2.imwrite('../frontend/public/pictures_saved/face_emotion/face_emotion_1.png', img)
            return Response({'file': 'face_emotion_1.png'})
```

There is 1 error and 1 warning that I have in the console but I can't seem to understand if they are related to the problem:

[image: Console React error + warning]

Also, the API call happens smoothly:

[image: Django log API calls]

I've tried to write and rewrite the code in different ways. I've tried to use event.preventDefault() and other variants but nothing seems to work. Something that I would like to add is that the current code works, and does exactly what I want it to do, except it reloads the page.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: You shouldn't be directly manipulating the DOM like you are. Also, are you running in StrictMode ?

Comment: No, I am not running in StrictMode. Could you please elaborate my mistakes? I am not very good with react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound the solution. The problem was in the API, to be more specific here:

```
cv2.imwrite('../frontend/public/pictures_saved/face_emotion/face_emotion_1.png', img)
```

Basically, in the Django server, I was saving a picture into the React server files. React "saw" that there were changes in the files (new files added/modified. not necessarily to edit a .js or .css. just add a simple .png) and re-rendered the whole page. Why does it work like that? I have no clue. I changed the path where the image would be saved to be outside the React's server files and it worked like a charm.